# Alternative to if statements inside for loops in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a data frame consisting of more than 400'000 rows. I am trying to organise my data in the following way:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(full_data)) {
    if (full_data$amount0In[i] > full_data$amount0Out[i]) {
      full_data$amount0[i] <- full_data$amount0In[i]
      full_data$amount1[i] <- -full_data$amount1Out[i]
    } else {
      full_data$amount0[i] <- -full_data$amount0Out[i]
      full_data$amount1[i] <- full_data$amount1In[i]
    }
  }
```

This code works but takes a very long time to compute. Are there any alternatives (e.g. vectorization) to make this code more efficient?

Comment: Probably - can you describe what your code is doing? Also, looks like just 1 loop - nested loops is when you have one loop inside another loop.

Comment: Don’t use loops. Work on the columns in the data frame directly. There are many, many, many questions on StackOverflow and tutorials on the web that will show you what to do.

Comment: I could not find specific examples of this around. Could you please share a good resource explaining this?

Comment: Here's a [blog post on vectorization](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/) aimed at new R users. Or download a free PDF of [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R's vectorization, you can do this - this is equivalent to your code, but will be much faster because it is vectorized.

```
In_gt_Out <- full_data$amount0In > full_data$amount0Out
full_data$amount0[In_gt_Out] <-  full_data$amount0In[In_gt_Out]
full_data$amount1[In_gt_Out] <- -full_data$amount1Out[In_gt_Out]

full_data$amount0[!In_gt_Out] <- -full_data$amount0Out[!In_gt_Out]
full_data$amount1[!In_gt_Out] <-  full_data$amount1In[!In_gt_Out]
```

There might be even simpler ways with `pmin` and `pmax`, but without any sample data or a description of the goal, it's hard to be sure what's going on.

Comment: I have 4 columns, "amount0in", "amount0Out", "amount1In" and "amount1Out" which represent transactions, e.g. 2 amount0In and 4 amount1Out would represent a trade of 2 tokens of amount1 against 4 tokens of amount2. The objective is to classify them in two columns "amount0" (in this example = 2) and "amount1" (in this example = -4), with outflows as negative values and inflows as positive values. Hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
library(dplyr)
full_data <- full_data %>% mutate(
      amount0 = if_else(amount0In > amount0Out, amount0In,amount0Out),
      amount1 = if_else(amount1In > amount1Out, amount1In,amount1Out)
)
```